# How to get gulp build version for automatically refreshing css cache with PHP

Tags: php, css, wordpress, gulp

I am using a gulp build task to concat and minify multiple CSS files into a file called `app.min.css`.

Next, in Wordpress, I use this bit of code to include the css file:

```
 $version = '2.6';
 wp_enqueue_style( 'app.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/dist/app.min.css', array(), $version );
```

But unfortunately I need to manually update the version number every time I want to release a freshly build `app.min.css`. This way Wordpress understands it has serve a fresh CSS file to the clients browser.

Is it possible to detect a new gulp build version. So I don't have to tell Wordpress manually that it needs to refresh the current stylesheet?

```
// conceptual code
$version = getLatestGulpBuildVersion();
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a solution to this problem at work today. This might not be the best way, but it works.

At the end of the `gulp build` task you can create a `version.txt` file using the `gulp-file` package:

```
function deploy_version(dist_path) {
    let uniqueVersion = Date.now() + ( (Math.random() * 100000).toFixed());

    return gulp.src('src/**')
        .pipe(file('version.txt', uniqueVersion.toString()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(theme_path + dist_path));
}
```

Calling this function when the build is completed, like so:

```
// build app.min.css
gulp.task('build-custom-css', function () {

   // ...
   // building stuff...

   deploy_version('assets/css/dist/');
 });
```

This way there is a `version.txt` file in the dist folder of the JS and CSS production dist folders. With content like a unique number like `157295773737144587` for example.

Now in `functions.php` we can simply load the version into the `$version` variable like so:

```
$version = file_get_contents( get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/dist/version.txt' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'app.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/dist/app.min.css', array(), $version );
```

By uploading the `dist` folder with the freshly build files like the `app.min.css` file. We also upload the `version.txt` file with a new unique version number inside of it. This way the browser will be forced to reload the css file automatically.